Properly destroying game objects from a List that is traversed in FixedUpdate()
[SerializeField] List<Cat> cats;
...

void FixedUpdate()
{
    foreach (var cat in cats) {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(cat.transform.position, cat.lockPosition); //*** error on this line
        // other logic
    }
}

// called from another script
public void CatShouldDie(Cat cat)
{
    ParticleSystem particleSystem = Instantiate(particleEffects.catDied, cat.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    cats.Remove(cat);
    Destroy(cat.gameObject);
    Destroy(particleSystem.gameObject, particleSystem.main.duration + particleSystem.main.startLifetime.constantMax);
}

The game runs fine for a little while (a few cats get destroyed without error), but what always happens eventually is this error: The object of type 'Cat' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
I know this happens because in the update loop a cat is being accessed that has been destroyed. But how do I handle this? I tried creating a catsToDestroy List that holds the objects to destroy and destroying them in LateUpdate() but I still had the same problem.

Do you destroy the cats from anywhere else? The code you've shown removes the cat from the list, so if you only ever get the error on cats that are still in the list, they must have been destroyed some other way, to still be in the list. Is this list persistent across scene loads, perhaps?

No, it's just a single scene and they don't get destroyed anywhere else.

Are they getting removed in the middle of the iteration?

I'm guessing they are, but the question is how to prevent that. The CatShouldDie method can be called at any time from another script.

Can you provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? Once we understand how these scripts inter-relate, we can find a solution to help them play nicely together. But that's more challenging if we can only see half the situation — we might come up with an over-engineered solution that handles every possible case when a simpler one would cover your use case.

When a cat is "killed", I'd leave it dead ... then in the Update "for" loop, check for dead cats. If dead, add that cat to a local "dead collection". Once you exit the for loop, delete any cats in the "dead collection" from the main "cats" collection. Avoids this particular "race" condition. In the rest of the app, simply test for "if cat not dead" when you encounter a cat reference. This is inline with the pattern of leaving the dead "laying around" for a time before "disappearing" them.
